# php - Do backend compression/decompression algorithms have any noticeable impact on perceived client-side page load speeds?

Tags: php, zlib, compression

I'm not sure if SO is the correct place for this question so please do not be too harsh if this is wrong forum :)

Our company is seeking to increase page load speeds and so far we have done a lot of the standard things (using cache, CDN, axe any unnecessary code/CSS, use raw JS instead of jQuery, etc).

I was reading up [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdeflate.php) on gz compression algorithms. One of the contributors (robin) makes a point of saying how `gzdeflate()` and `gzcompress()` were equally fast, but `gzinflate()` was consistently twice as fast as `gzuncompress()`.

If we compress/decompress static HTML using one of these Zlib functions, I suspect the **backend execution component** (of the whole page load process) would not even be noticeable by the user. But 1MB of HTML being served up as 800kB HTML may be noticed.

My question is this: does backend script execution using a custom compression/decompression algorithm have any impact on page load speeds for the end user, even if the compression/decompression algorithm is highly complex? (many function calls, backend script itself is sizable, liberally uses not-inexpensive functions such as `substr_count()`, etc.)

Comment: Whatever happens in the PHP code will not affect the page compression speed. From what I gather, when compression is enabled, PHP buffers all output and just before the output is sent to the client it is compressed. The only thing that will make the actual compression slower is increasing the number of bytes to be compressed.

Comment: My bad with title...meant client side not client size :)

Comment: @Mike so if you had some magical way to compress 1MB file to 10 bytes, but it required a script which took 1 second to execute (extreme example but trying to make a point) user wouldn't notice this in the page load speed?

Comment: If you could theoretically compress 1 MB down to 10 bytes the user is likely not going to notice overall because it probably would have taken at least 1 second to download the 1 MB file to begin with. But if you're adding 1 second to page load speed to save only a few KB then people are going to start noticing it. But again, this is theoretical. Your page is almost never going to be 1 MB of HTML (and if there is, something's probably wrong), and you're not going to be able to compress 1 MB down to 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are already using a compression/decompression method, I would say: No.
The compression rate are similar, you could choose the algorithm depending on the CPU usage but answering the question, a couple of extra bits won't be noticeable for the final user. The most expensive operations are the "time to first byte" (TTFB).

You can do your own benchmarks in the chrome dev tool, here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#view-network-timing-details-for-a-specific-resource)

Take references by looking what kind of compression are using big websites such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.